# GridseachCV - ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [33 1]

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, keras, grid-search

I am trying to use gridsearchCV with on my keras model, but seem to have ran into a error which i am not sure how to interpret.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_cnn_phoneme_generator_fit.py", line 229, in <module>
    grid_results=grid.fit(train_input,train_output)
  File "/home/c/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 940, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, groups, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "/home/c/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 541, in _fit
    X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
  File "/home/c/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 206, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "/home/c/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [33, 1]
```

Here is the model and how i apply it.

```
def model3(kernel_number = 200, kernel_shape = (window_height,3)):
    #stride = 1
    #dim = 40
    #window_height = 8
    #splits = ((40-8)+1)/1 = 33
    #next(test_generator())
    #next(train_generator(batch_size))

    #kernel_number = 200
    list_of_input = [Input(shape = (window_height,total_frames_with_deltas,3)) for i in range(splits)]
    list_of_conv_output = []
    list_of_max_out = []
    for i in range(splits):
        if splits == 1:
            list_of_conv_output.append(Conv2D(filters = kernel_number , kernel_size = kernel_shape, activation = 'relu')(list_of_input[i]))
            list_of_max_out.append((MaxPooling2D(pool_size=((1,11)))(list_of_conv_output[i])))
        else:
            list_of_conv_output.append(Conv2D(filters = 200 , kernel_size = (window_height,3) , activation = 'relu')(list_of_input[i]))
            list_of_max_out.append((MaxPooling2D(pool_size=((1,11)))(list_of_conv_output[i])))

    merge = keras.layers.concatenate(list_of_max_out)
    print merge.shape
    reshape = Reshape((total_frames/total_frames,-1))(merge)

    dense1 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_1")(reshape)
    dense2 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_2")(dense1)
    dense3 = Dense(units = 145 , activation = 'softmax', name = "dense_3")(dense2)


    model = Model(inputs = list_of_input , outputs = dense3)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="SGD" , metrics = [metrics.categorical_accuracy])

    reduce_lr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto', epsilon=0.001, cooldown=0)
    stop  = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')
    log=csv_logger = CSVLogger('/home/c/kaldi-trunk/dnn/training_'+str(total_frames)+"_"+str(dim)+"_"+str(window_height)+"_"+str(batch_size)+".csv")
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="/media/c/E2302E68302E443F/Timit-dataset/timit/fbank/nn/"+str(total_frames)+"_"+str(dim)+"_"+str(window_height)+"_"+str(batch_size)+".hdf5",save_best_only=True)

    if len(sys.argv) == 7:
        model.load_weigts(weights)

    print model.summary()

    #raw_input("okay?")
    #hist_current = model.fit_generator(train_generator(batch_size),
    #                    steps_per_epoch=10,
    #                    epochs = 100000,
    #                    verbose = 1,
    #                    validation_data = test_generator(),
    #                    validation_steps=1,
    #                    pickle_safe = True,
    #                    workers = 4,
    #                    callbacks = [log,checkpoint])
    return model


#model3()

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model3,epochs = 10,batch_size = 1,verbose=1)
kernel_number = [10,50,100,150,200,250]
kernel_shape = [(window_height,3),(window_height,5),(window_height,8)]
param_grid = dict(kernel_number = kernel_number , kernel_shape=kernel_shape)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
train_input,train_output = next(train_generator(1))
grid_results=grid.fit(train_input,train_output)

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

The model has multiple inputs, 33 in total.These inputs are given by a data_generator, which spits out a list of length 33 with numpy.arrays if shape (batch_size, 1 , 40,8,3). Could the problem be that it not able to handle list? or why am i getting this error?

for batch_size = 100

```
print len(train_input)
print train_input[0].shape
print train_output.shape

33
(100, 8, 45, 3)
(100, 1, 145)
```

Comment: Whats the shape of `train_input`,`train_output` that re supplied to gridsearch `fit()`?

Comment: `train_input` is a list of length 33 with numpy.ndarray of shapes (batch_size,1,8,45,3)
`train_output` is a numpy.ndarray (1,145)

Why a list you ask?.. well my model has 33 inputs, and the only way i can feed them is like this.

Comment: Can you print the actual shape of `train_input, train_output` before this line `grid_results=grid.fit(train_input,train_output)`?

Comment: Why is `train_output` length (1, 145) ie the first dimension is 1 (means 1 row) and `train_input` has 33 rows?? Most scikit (maybe all) estimators only support 2-d arrays for X (`train_input`)  of shape [n_samples, n_features].

Comment: @VivekKumar added the information..  1 label predicted out of 145 possible label.

Comment: @VivekKumar the model has multiple inputs, 33 inputs. so one batch will have 33 inputs, in which each receive an image of shape 8,45,3

Comment: And what does the 100 represents? Have you read the documentation of GridSearchCV?

Comment: 100. represent th number of samples..

Comment: @VivekKumar There isn't anything wrong with the input/output dimensions seen from a keras perspective.

Comment: I cannot say about Keras. But GridSearchCV (or most of scikit estimators for that matter) take `X` (features), `y` (targets). `X` should be 2-d (not 4-d as in your case), in which rows represents the different samples, and columns represents the features. `y` can be 1-d or 2-d but number of rows (1st dimension) should be same as number of rows (1st dimension) in X. Yours does not comply, hence the error.

Comment: How does it then handle networks with multiple inputs?

Comment: I am not quite sure I am getting you. Are you saying that Gridsearch can handle some other similar data but not this one? Or are you asking for a way to handle this data?

Comment: Well... The network OP has shown has multiple inputs and one output. 
Not a one input  - one output network. 

Keras handles multiple input by indexing the inputs in to a list in which first entry would be for first input. and the numpy array stored in the first entry would be a shape of (samples, feature_dim)... which seem to be the case. 
Keras has a wrapper for using scikit-learn.   How does scikit-learn handle multiple input neural network..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/) states:

> You can use Sequential Keras models **(single-input only)** as part of your Scikit-Learn workflow via the wrappers found at keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.py.

So, it is not possible.

I guess a different solution has to be found.

Comment: Here the SOLUTION to pass multiple inputs in GridSearch CV: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824968/grid-search-for-keras-with-multiple-inputs/62512554#62512554