# How to carry out hyperparameter tuning for MLP model in Keras via GridsearchCV?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, mlp

I have created a model using the function and am passing two embeddings as an input to the model in the form of 1D arrays. While trying to fit Grid search on the inputs, it throws an error stating "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples". I even tried to reshape the inputs but in vain, since inputs are in 1D.

So the question is how to do hyperparameter tuning of keras MLP model with multiple inputs and a single output?

The other question is how to get a model summary? I tried using model.summary(), but it is not working with the model created through a function.

```
def create_baseline():
    
    activation = 'relu'
    dropout_rate = 0.2
    kernel_initializer = 'uniform'
    optimizer = 'adam'
    learning_rate = 0.001
    latent_dim = 50
    
    # Create model

    user_input = Input(shape = (1, ), name = 'user-input')
    user_embedding = Embedding(num_users + 1, latent_dim, name = 'user-embedding')(user_input)
    user_vec = Flatten(name = 'user-flatten')(user_embedding)

    movie_input = Input(shape = (1, ), name = 'movie-input')
    movie_embedding = Embedding(num_movies + 1, latent_dim, name = 'movie-embedding')(movie_input)
    movie_vec = Flatten(name = 'movie-flatten')(movie_embedding)

    merged = concatenate([user_vec, movie_vec], axis = 1, name = 'user-movie-concat')
    merged_dropout = Dropout(dropout_rate)(merged)

    fc_1 = Dense(128, name = 'fc-1', kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, activation = activation, activity_regularizer = l2(0.01))(merged_dropout)
    fc_1_dropout = Dropout(dropout_rate, name = 'fc-1-dropout')(fc_1)
    fc_2 = Dense(64, name = 'fc-2', kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, activation = activation, activity_regularizer = l2(0.01))(fc_1_dropout)
    fc_2_dropout = Dropout(dropout_rate, name = 'fc-2-dropout')(fc_2)
    fc_3 = Dense(32, name = 'fc-3', kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, activation = activation, activity_regularizer = l2(0.01))(fc_2_dropout)
    fc_3_dropout = Dropout(dropout_rate, name = 'fc-3-dropout')(fc_3)
    fc_4 = Dense(1, name = 'fc-4', kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, activation = activation)(fc_3_dropout)

    model = Model([user_input, movie_input], fc_4)
    model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = [rmse, 'mae'])
    
    return model


from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 2, verbose = 0)

# Create a KerasRegressor
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn = create_baseline, epochs = 10, batch_size = 8, verbose = 0, callbacks = [early_stop])

# Defining the parameters to tune.

mlp_params = {'batch_size': [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64], 
              'learning_rate': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1],
              'dropout_rate': [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
              'optimizer': ['Adam', 'RMSprop', 'SGD', 'Adagrad'],
              'kernel_initializer': ['uniform', 'normal', 'glorot_normal', 'glorot_uniform', 'he_normal', 'he_uniform']}

# Using Grid Search to tune the hyperparameters. 

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

gs_mlp_model = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid = mlp_params, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', cv = 5, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 1)

gs_mlp_model.fit([X_train_1.UserID.values, X_train_1.MovieID.values], y_train_1.values)


# The error is:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-157-dcc10ddae7b6> in <module>
----> 1 gs_mlp_model.fit([X_train_1.UserID.values, X_train_1.MovieID.values], y_train_1.values)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    648             refit_metric = 'score'
    649 
--> 650         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
    651         fit_params = _check_fit_params(X, fit_params)
    652 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    246     """
    247     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 248     check_consistent_length(*result)
    249     return result
    250 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    210     if len(uniques) > 1:
    211         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 212                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    213 
    214 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 800167]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62512554/10375049

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?